# Do I need a Vault if I use Service Binding Operator?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am playing with OpenShift 4.10 and trying to figure out how to manage credentials. What I get so far is that Service Binding Operator will allow developers to deploy their apps without having to explicitly manage credentials and other connection data in their code.

Do I need to configure a vault where Service Binding Operator will store these credentials? I couldn't find any reference indicating that this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the GitHub [link](https://github.com/redhat-developer/service-binding-operator/issues/75) :

The ServiceBindingRequest operator could run its own Vault server (managed by the Banzai/vault operator ) where it would 'store' credentials for backing services after picking it up from the backing service CR's status/spec/secret

The service binding controller could then add the required annotations in the DeploymentConfig and depend on the banzai/vault operator to react to it, and directly inject credentials into pods.

You can also refer to documents on [Vault Kubernetes deployment guide](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-raft-deployment-guide#concepts-overview) and [Introducing the service binding operator](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/12/19/introducing-the-service-binding-operator#) for more information.

Comment: The GitHub link says: "it could". It does even say it can. So it si merely giving a suggestion. And there is no indication in the ticket that the suggestion was implemented. And the two other articles you posted don't say a word about secrets in the context of service binding operator, one talks about secret, the other talks about the operator. Nothing that talks about how the operator deals with secrets.